# Sort Pandas dataframe column index by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sort dataframe by column index. The issue is my columns are 'dates' dd/mm/yyyy directly imported from my excel. For ex:

```
    10/08/20  12/08/20 11/08/20
0   2.0        6.0       15.0
1   6.0        11.0      8.0
2   4.0        7.0       3.0
3   7.0        12.0      2.0
4   12.0       5.0       7.0
```

The output I want is:

```
    10/08/20  11/08/20 12/08/20
0   2.0        15.0      6.0
1   6.0        8.0       11.0
2   4.0        3.0       7.0
3   7.0        2.0       12.0
4   12.0       7.0       5.0
```

I am using

```
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

It is giving me following error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime'
> and 'str'

I want to do it in panda dataframe. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do two of the dates have a `'.'` at the end and one doesn't?

Comment: Please ignore '.' that was by mistake. Really sorry about that confusion

Comment: @anmol sureka , please try the edited code. As the columns were not in datetime format as you edited in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the **'.' at the end** of date from the data shource sheet.
the for this data

```
    10-08-2020  12-08-2020  11-08-2020
0   2           6           15
1   6           11          8
2   4           7           3
3   7           12          2
4   12          5           7
```

try this

```
import datetime as dt
df.columns=pd.Series(df.columns).apply(lambda d: dt.datetime(d, dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y')))
df.sort_index(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(".", "")
```

Then:

```
df.sort_index(axis = 1)
```

**Update**: as Ch3steR mentioned in the comments. For removing "."

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip(".")
```

Using [`str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) to generalize, as `day.month.year` is valid format, using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) would replace every `.`

### Example:

```
s = pd.Series(["1.2.2020."])
pd.to_datetime(s.str.replace('.', ''))
# 0   2020-12-20         # Interpeted wrong
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

pd.to_datetime(s.str.rstrip('.'))
# 0   2020-01-02
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @Ch3steR COOL! Didn't know about the function. Updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Added some details, feel free to revert changes if not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the fact that **you are mixing string types with date types**. Either all your column names are strings or all are dates **but you cannot have both mixed.**

For example

```
l=[[2.0, 6.0, 15.0],
   [6.0, 11.0, 8.0],
   [4.0, 7.0, 3.0],
   [7.0, 12.0, 2.0],
   [12.0, 5.0, 7.0]]

d = pd.DataFrame(l, columns =['10/08/20',  '12/08/20', '11/08/20']) # column names are strings
```

yields

```
   10/08/20  12/08/20  11/08/20
0       2.0       6.0      15.0
1       6.0      11.0       8.0
2       4.0       7.0       3.0
3       7.0      12.0       2.0
4      12.0       5.0       7.0
```

Now if I want to sort by column names I type

```
d.sort_index(axis = 1)

   10/08/20  11/08/20  12/08/20
0       2.0      15.0       6.0
1       6.0       8.0      11.0
2       4.0       3.0       7.0
3       7.0       2.0      12.0
4      12.0       7.0       5.0
```

If on the other hand, column names were dates as in

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d = pd.DataFrame(l, columns =[parse('10/08/20'),  parse('12/08/20'), parse('11/08/20')])
```

we will have

```
   2020-10-08  2020-12-08  2020-11-08   #now column names are dates
0         2.0         6.0        15.0
1         6.0        11.0         8.0
2         4.0         7.0         3.0
3         7.0        12.0         2.0
4        12.0         5.0         7.0
```

Again you can sort them using the same

```
details.sort_index(axis = 1)
  
   2020-10-08  2020-11-08  2020-12-08
0         2.0        15.0         6.0
1         6.0         8.0        11.0
2         4.0         3.0         7.0
3         7.0         2.0        12.0
4        12.0         7.0         5.0
```

and will give you no error.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for reply. '.' is not in the source sheet. It came here by mistake. Sorry about that. When I import excel, my dates are imported in datetime.datetime format and because of which it is giving me error : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'